# Hiding DIV with onclick functions - looking for a cleaner way to achieve the same result

Tags: javascript

First, I'd like to apologize if this is easily searchable; I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I don't know exactly what to search (hence why I'm asking here!)

Basically, I have some code that shows/hides divs based on what nav button the user clicks, eliminating the need for multiple pages of HTML.  I have a working solution in JS, but my problem is that it seems way too blocky and needlessly complicated.

I know they'res a more elegant solution out there somewhere. However everything I looked at only deals with hiding/showing divs when you press one button, not multiple, as would be the case with a nav bar.

So, if you could point out a few different avenues to research, I'd appreciate it!

JS:

```
function hideContent1(){

    var a = document.getElementById("zero");
    var b = document.getElementById("one");
    var c = document.getElementById("two");
    var d = document.getElementById("threeA");
    var e = document.getElementById("threeB");


    if(a.style.display = "none"){
        document.getElementById('zero').style.display = "block";
    }

    if(b.style.display = "none"){
        document.getElementById('one').style.display = "block";
    }

    if(c.style.display = "block"){
        document.getElementById('two').style.display = "none";
    }

    if(d.style.display = "block"){
        document.getElementById('threeA').style.display = "none";
    }

    if(e.style.display = "block"){
        document.getElementById('threeB').style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

This repeats three times, with slightly different IF statements, for the three different nav buttons that can be pressed.

Like I said before, this code works fine, it's just needlessly bulky.  What would be a better way to complete this task?

Comment: Your current code looks broken, it should not `work fine`: `if(a.style.display = "none"){` but `=` is assignment, not comparison, all `if`s will be fulfilled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the assignments inside the `if`s were just typos, and assuming that the styles toggle between `none` and `block`, you may simply assign the `block` or `none` style regardless - if it doesn't change the existing style, nothing will happen.

You might consider using classes instead, to make the code less repetitive - eg, give `a` and `b` a class of `content2`, and give the rest a class of `content1`. Then, on `hideContent1()`, hide every `content1`, while showing all `content2`:

```
function hideContent1(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.content2')
    .forEach(elm => elm.style.display = 'block');
  document.querySelectorAll('.content1')
    .forEach(elm => elm.style.display = 'none');
}
```

Note that `NodeList.prototype.forEach` is a somewhat new method, so if you want to support older browsers, either use a polyfill, or convert the NodeList to an array before calling `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combined id selector, then get all elements using `querySelectorAll` and finally iterate and do the same. Although the `if` statements are not necessary since you are just togging them in case it's already visible and setting `block` doesn't make any change. In your current code, it will be always true since it's an assignment(`=`) and value is a non-empty string which would be [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

For getting elements based on CSS selector you can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method  and for iterating over the returned [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) collection use [`NodeList#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method([polyfill for older browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill)).

```
function hideContent1() {
  // get elements to show
  var show = document.querySelectorAll('#zero,#one')
  // get elements to hide
  var hide = document.querySelectorAll('#two,#threeA,#threeB');

  // iterate and update
  show.forEach(ele => ele.style.display = 'block')
  hide.forEach(ele => ele.style.display = 'none')

}
```

*FYI :* For grouping multiple elements you can use a common class which is always better than combining multiple selectors.

Answer (score -1):

How about making it as a function?

for example:

```
function switchDisplay(source, target) {
    if (source.style.display === 'none')  {
        target.style.display = 'block'
    }

    if (source.style.display === 'block') {
        target.style.display = 'none'
    }
}
```

Assuming the functionality is the one you really want to have & besides the typo as mentioned in the comments.